# Customising row layout in expandable recycler view

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview, drawable

I have an expandable recycler view, with parent and child relation. When parent row item is clicked, children show up.

I'd like to show a small tooltip like triangle at the bottom of the parent, when it expands, pointing to the children beneath it. And revert back to usual layout when it collapses. My question is how do I get to have that little triangle at the bottom of each parent when it's expanding.

Is 9 patch img the only way to do this? Is there an alternative? Thanks!

Comment: vector images are good for any size.

Comment: you can use image view at bottom of parent and show it when child appears and hide it when child collapse. imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Answer (score 0):

you can use image view at bottom of parent and show it when child appears and hide it when child collapse.

```
imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```